# 2.8 Outline on Curve Objects

Tags: bezier-curves, eevee-render-engine

Is there a way to hide these outlines that are on curve objects? They kind of get in the way in my render preview. [image]

Answer (score 2):

switch off overlays (3d viewport - top right)

Answer (score 2):

You can also go into the overlays section and untick Normals in the Curve Edit section. so only those are hidden and not all overlays.[image]